# Ternary operator and increment operator

Tags: c++, ternary-operator

Is this a valid / sound way of resetting a counter if a condition is not met? It is the most compact way I could think of.

```
int counter = 0;
int a,b;

// Do .. and assign a and b 

counter = ((a<b) ? counter++ : 0);
```

Comment: The aim should be to write this in the most maintainable way possible not the most compact way possible.

Comment: You might also consider resetting or incrementing `counter` wherever you would be setting `condition`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are already assigning to `counter`, so don't use `++` as well.

```
counter = condition ? (counter + 1) : 0;
```

Comment: Doesn't it produce the same result?

Comment: No. `counter++` evaluates to the *current* value of `counter`, then increments it. You would be assigning the old value of `counter` back to `counter` after you've incremented. I *think* you could use `++counter` as a hard-to-read-but-correct variant, but it's much clearer to simply use the side-effect-free `counter + 1`.

Comment: And if one wants to write really fancy code, just do counter += condition * 1;

Comment: @chepner: You might be assigning the old value of counter back to counter, or you might be assigning 42 to it. It's UB, and I'm pretty sure that `i = ++i` is also UB.

Comment: I realized having multiple side effects on the RHS was UB (e.g., `x = i++ + ++i`), but couldn't remember if the RHS was defined to be fully evaluated prior to assigning to the LHS. I'd say it's something to avoid as confusing even if it were well-defined.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of `counter = (condition ? counter++ : 0);` is undefined as there's no sequencing point. (The ternary is not sequenced, and neither is assignment).

It's similar in form to `i = i++;`

Comment: Could you please elaborate further? I tought the right hand operation was carried out before assignment?

Comment: Your version doesn't reset `counter`; it's just a no-op.

Comment: Oops. Hope my boss didn't see that.

Comment: Wait, counter += 0 will make no change, I need to set the counter to 0 if condition is not met